# git diff command to exclude some folders and files

Tags: git, gerrit

I am currently using the following Git diff command to get the list of files changes. I want to exclude certain folders (say `datafiles`) and files(`.DSstore`). Is there a way to do this?

```
git diff --no-index /Users/USERNAME/Documents/FWintegration/ingo2/ukon_4355c1 /Users/USERNAME/Documents/FWintegration/ingo2mirror/ingo2mirror
```

Comment: And...I just realized both my answers are stupid with the `--noindex` option.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of files that have changed? `git diff` isn't a good tool for that. `git log` and, at a much lower level, `git rev-list` are better tools.

Comment: Although `git diff --stat` might be helpful, depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: @PaulHicks I'm not sure *git* is a good tool at all in this situation, now that I've looked at "--no-index".  Maybe some git expert will come along and school me.  I certainly am not one.

Comment: @PaulHicks & zzxyz- why do you say git is not a good tool here ?also what is wrong with `--no-index`

Comment: It is diffing two files where at least one of them is not in version control. find+diff / ack / ag and other tools like that might be more suitable.

Comment: @user3682248 - `--no-index` is explicitly asking a version control system to not use version control information--if I understand the documentation correctly.  I'd compare it to using Netbeans or Visual Studio to edit text files.  Nothing really *wrong* with it, but there might be a better tool for the job.

Comment: @all - My exact requirement is I have two folders on a Mac ..want to compare them excluding some folder and want to know what all files have changes, as a followup I would like to copy some of the changed files ,is there a command-line utility which can help me do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
git diff -- ':!unwantedpath'
```

For example, `git diff -- ':!foo/bar/datafiles' ':!*.DSstore'`.

But it is a relatively new feature, so it works only if you are using a new version of Git. I don't remember in which version it was introduced, but it's some version after 2.10.0.

Comment: This is much better than my answer, but not nearly as hilarious.

Answer (score 3):

Okay...my third answer.  Unfortunately this one is the *most* complicated, but it actually works with `--no-index`:

```
git diff | awk '{if (/^diff --git/) {if (/d1\/\S*$/){display=0}else{display=1}};if (display==1) {print}}'
```

Each file diff `git diff` performs starts with "diff --git".  So...we have awk look for that line.  If it finds it, and then doesn't like it, it stops printing until it finds a diff --git it likes.

So, the only part of the awk statement you modify is `if (/d1\/\S*$/)`  This is how it filters...if this regular expression matches, it'll ignore this diff--not print it).  This filters out "d1/" followed by any number of non-whitespace characters up until the end of the line (so it's looking at the *2nd* filename only and not the first.)  For your example, you'd want the if to be:

```
if (/datafiles\/\S*$/ || /\.DSstore$/)
```

EDIT:
If this is too insane for you, and no one provides a better solution, I'd highly recommend checking out "Beyond Compare" which is a crazy powerful directory/file comparison tool with a nice UI.

Comment: Yes! This actually works with --no-index. Sadly, it removes the color coding from the git diff lines. Any idea how to preserve that?

Answer (score 0):

Simply by using `--exclude` argument.
You can ignore **folders** / **files** with *exact names* or even *having a regex pattern* using wild card operator `*`.

Example:

```
diff -r /folder1/ /folder2/  --exclude="*.iml" --exclude=".idea" --exclude=".git" --exclude="target" --exclude=".DS_Store"
```